# Remove MKMapView Annotations with a certain pinColor?

Tags: iphone, ios, annotations, mkmapview

Is it possible to remove all annotations on a given MKMapView of a given pinColor? I'm trying to clear all user-entered annotations (pins) on my map before displaying new ones for a part of my app, but I didn't know how granular I can be in selectively removing annotations...

I'd like to just remove all annotations that have MKPinAnnotationColorGreen (green) pins, but I'd also be able to simply remove all pins entered by the user, if there's a way I could track those.

I know I could simply do:

```
[myMapView removeAnnotations:myMapView.annotations];
```

... then redraw all the annotations I want, but that seems like a waste of resources.

Any advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not able to test this right now, but have you tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pinColor == %d",  MKPinAnnotationColorGreen];
[myMapView removeAnnotations:[myMapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

As for the ones added by the user, you might need to keep track of those yourself.  You could also create your own subclass of MKPinAnnotation.  On that subclass, add the property

```
@property (nonatomic, BOOL) addedByUser;
```

.  You could set addedByUser to true if they were added by the user and then filter out those using a similar approach above (eg. @"addedByUser == YES").

Comment: Two very good ideas - I didn't think of creating another subclass (I currently have a custom subclass already, and differentiate types based on pin color), and this might be the best solution going forward (I'm going to be adding more types of locations as time goes on).

Comment: I ended up removing based on predicates, but I had to use the title value instead of the pinColor, simply because the pinColor doesn't seem accessible through myMapView.annotations...

Comment: Hmmm...I am little bit surprised that pinColor won't filter by predicates.  The documentation says that they are properties, so I would expect them to follow the keypath rules.  But anyway, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe keeping each group of annotations in an array (NSMutableArray) of pointers to those annotations and then removing only them?

Comment: That would probably work, but I think Matthew's answer is a little more suitable for my purposes.