# Remove a specific annotation from mapview

Tags: iphone, mapkit

In my mapview I am creating pins like `cafe`, `bar`, `night_club`, and `restaurant`. How can I code to remove only the a specific point, `cafe` for example.  I have used the code below to successfully remove ALL the annotations.  I can't figure out how to delete one specific one (instead of all of them).

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in routeMapView.annotations) 
{
  if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) 
  {
    [routeMapView removeAnnotation:index=annotation];
  }
}
```

Comment: how are u adding u r annotations..?

Comment: How are your PINS created? are you making a class for each pin type (coffee, bar, etc) or you giving them tags?

Comment: What hpnd my dear ?Have you got ur answer or not ?

Answer (score 4):

It may help you please try to use this one.

```
for (id annotation in mapView.annotations)
{
    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"cafe"])
          [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSPredicate for the situation like

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pinName == %@",  @"Cafe"];
[myMapView removeAnnotations:[myMapView.annotations filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Above will remove all the annotations named cafe.

For more info you can see this answer
[Remove MKMapView Annotations with a certain pinColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049280/remove-mkmapview-annotations-with-a-certain-pincolor)