# NSPredicate with a sub-property

Tags: objective-c, nspredicate, subclassing

Is it possible to create NSPredicate to filter based on lets say object.name? (object is a property of the object I'd like to filter).

**Edit:** By filter, I mean I have a list of initials and when the user taps on one, I'd like to remove all pins where object.name starts with that initial.

Example: I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049280/remove-mkmapview-annotations-with-a-certain-pincolor) where the accepted answer shows how to filter the pins on a map view using NSPredicate and subclassing. This is almost what I want.

But in my case, I have a CustomPin class, which inherits MKAnnotation. My custom pin has a property named "object", which is of class Friend, which inherits NSManagedObject.

Now I'd like to filter by **pin.object.name**.

Extra: (If it's not possible due to this part, then I'll just create a superclass for Friend and Pet, and make them both inherit name from it, but currently it's not done like that, so I've added this part too).

And to make things more hectic, object can be of class Friend or Pet, both inheriting NSManagedObject and having property "name".

Here's my CustomPin class:

```
@interface CustomPin : NSObject <MKAnnotation, OCGrouping>

- (CustomPin *)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate title:(NSString *)title subtitle:(NSString *)subtitle pinType:(NSNumber *)pinType;

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *pinType;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *groupTag;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSManagedObject *object;
```

Here's my Friend class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone_no;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
```

And here's my Pet class:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * longitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * phone_no;
```

Obviously the class names are just for the examples sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    NSString *nameOfObject = @"some name";
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"object.name like %@", nameOfObject]; 
    // or "object.name == %@"

    NSArray *filteredArray = [arrayOfPins filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

[More about using predicates with key-paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001794-SW3)

Comment: I don't have pin.name. I have pin.object.name.

Comment: you can use a predicate with a key path  eg:- `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"object.name like %@", nameOfObject];`

I edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSArray *b = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pin.object.name = %@", required_name]];
```